# Filebrowser does not append slashes to files path when picking an image in django admin panel

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-filebrowser

Using python 2.7, django 1.4.1, filebrowser 3.5.0, grappelli 2.4.2, win7 x64

So heres my problem:

Im creating a object, and trying to attach an image to it:

Clicking on search:
[image: filebrowser attaching file]

Navigating through folders to get to my file, and picking it:
[image]

After i pick it, this is the path it returns:

[image]

Attaching model itself:

```
class EntryManager(models.Manager):
    def active(self):
        return super(EntryManager, self).get_query_set().filter(is_active=True)

class Services(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20, help_text = 'Nazwa oferowanej usługi', verbose_name='Usługa')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, help_text = 'Odnośnik, generowany automatycznie na podstawie nazwy', unique=True,verbose_name='Odnośnik')
    icon = FileBrowseField(verbose_name='Ikona', max_length=255, directory="images/", extensions=[".jpg",'.png','.gif'], blank=True, null=True,help_text = '.jpg, .png, .gif')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(help_text='Zaznacz aby obiekt był widoczny dla użytkowników', default=False)

    objects = EntryManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']
        verbose_name = "Usługę"
        verbose_name_plural = "Usługi"
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return '/uslugi/%s/' % self.slug
```

I have no idea where to search for a problem at the moment, could any1 help?

**edit:**

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

from filebrowser.sites import site


#when on dev, serve media files
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^admin/filebrowser/', include(site.urls)),
    url(r'^uslugi/?$', 'services.views.services'),
)

#when on dev, serve media files
if settings.DEBUG:
    # static files (images, css, javascript, etc.)
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
        'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}))
```

and part of settings.py

```
import os
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__) + "../../")
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'site_media/media')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'site_media/static')
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'site_media/admin_media')

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'grappelli',
    'filebrowser',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'services'
)
```

Comment: I had the same problem my Polish Bro :) That's why I used `django-filebrowser` with `grappeli` and workds fine now.. my moded field definition is `image = FileBrowseField("Image", max_length=200, directory="products/",  format='image')`

Comment: im using grappelli aswell, and after i modified my model so it looked exactly like yours the problem still remains :/

Comment: can You post `INSTALLED_APPS` and urls ? and have You installed it via `pip` ? Are you using Linux as OS ?

Comment: And maybe try with some very simple model with only one filed `FileBrowseField`

Comment: attached urls and installed apps, yup installed in a virtualenv via pip on win7 64bit, tho django itself is 32bit

Answer (score 1):

After reading yours `urls.py` I need to show You [Documentation](http://django-filebrowser.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#installation):

> In your url.py import the default FileBrowser site:

```
from filebrowser.sites import site
```

> and add the following URL-patterns **(before any admin-urls):**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
   url(r'^admin/filebrowser/', include(site.urls)),
)
```

So only differences between You and my new project are:

1. I'm using Linux Ubuntu x86 on VirtualBox undex Windows 7
2. I have `/admin/file-browser` BEFORE any admin-urls:

> ```
> from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
> from django.contrib import admin
> from filebrowser.sites import site
> from django.conf.urls.static import static
> from django.conf import settings
>
> admin.autodiscover()
>
> urlpatterns = static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) + patterns('',
>     url(r'^grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')),
>     url(r'^admin/filebrowser/', include(site.urls)),    
>     url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
>     url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
>     url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
>     url(r'^',  include('django.contrib.flatpages.urls')),
> )
> ```

Comment: i guess its the os, gonna deploy n check if its bugged on linux aswell since whole app is almost ready by now (i made so much effort to dev on win7 already, that im not gonna give up just right now:>)

Comment: probably it's something with `\\ ` and `/` because I don't any clue here.. installed yesterday via `virtualenv --distribute` and `pip install django-filebrowser`

Comment: switched to ubuntu like a week ago, loving it ;)